# angular 2 provide browser storage functionality like session storage?

Tags: angular

I want to store object in client browser memory but my object size is too large. So, session storage and local storage not work for me. If there is any other option to store data on client side. please provide your suggestion.

Comment: Why not in server side?

Comment: We don't want to store that object in server. we need to store that in client browser as we have more than ten list in ten tab.

Comment: Simply create a service that will hold your data. I usually call it `SessionService`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is opinionated.

I recommend you to transform your data in a map like data structure(if it is not already), then store only the keys in client side. (For example userId, pageId, currentAction etc etc). Then fetch the data from the serverside on demand.

Thus this is more like a hybrid approach.

Another approach is to store parts of your object in client side and parts of it in server side. Based on the usage frequency, you can switch data from server to client vice-versa. (similar to how cache works)

If you store heavy objects in client side, the application will become slow.